# How to find absolute path using a relative path in c#

Tags: c#, absolute-path

I have a path stored in a variable say

```
string partialPath = '\editors\tinymce'
```

I want to get the entire path of the above fie. The actual path of the above file is 'D:\Back up\editors\tinymce'. How can I do this in C#. Thanks

Comment: Warning: Don't prepend "\" in the path or else you will get D:\editors\tinymce

Comment: Relative paths are relative to the *current* folder, or a specific folder. If your current folder is in C:, the path points to `c:\editors\tinymce`. If you want this path to refer to another drive you have to specify it. Why `D:` instead of eg, `E:\` or `Z:\`?

Answer (score 3):

```
var dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var output = Path.Combine(dir, partialPath);
```

Answer (score 3):

This might do the trick for you

```
string partialPath = "\editors\tinymce";
string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(partialPath);
```

output:

> D:\editors\tinymce

Whereas

This might do the trick for you

```
string partialPath = "editors\tinymce";
fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(partialPath);
```

output:

> D:\Back up\editors\tinymce

Comment: But if I use it , I get this Path

Comment: @SamDaniel which is the correct result. That's what a *relative* path is - relative to some folder. If none is specified, the folder is the current one. If you want it to point to a *different* drive, you need to specify what you want. The OS won't search all attached drives to find a match

Answer (score 0):

please try with below code:

code:

```
string partialPath = "\editors\tinymce";
var output = Server.MapPath(partialPath);
string str = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(partialPath);
```

you can get path on output var and str string.

let us know.

Comment: If i use this, My C drive is being pointed out, but the actual file is in the D Drive

Comment: string partialPath = "\\editors\\tinymce";
var output = Server.MapPath(partialPath);